Cannot get microphone to work properly in WebView
I'm having trouble getting the microphone to work within a WebView.
There's a webpage that I know I can use to test my microphone. It works perfectly in Safari. When I talk, I can see the bursts on the test area that correspond to what I'm saying.
I wrote an app to display the site in a WebView. I run the app, click Allow when it asks if I want to allow the site to use my microphone. When I talk, the bursts on the test area do NOT correspond to what I'm saying. In fact, the bursts in a sort of heartbeat pattern. It's like it doesn't hear my voice at all. It seems like a test pattern.
I feel like I'm doing something obviously wrong. Any help would be appreciated.
I'm running the following:

Sonoma 14.6.1
Xcode 15.4
Simulator 15.4 (iPhone 15 pro)

Here's the code:
ContentView.swift
import UIKit
import WebKit
import AVFoundation

class WebViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler {
    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Setup WKWebView
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(webView)
        
        // Add script message handler
        let contentController = WKUserContentController()
        contentController.add(self, name: "logHandler")
        webConfiguration.userContentController = contentController

        // Add Auto Layout constraints
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])

        openMicrophoneTestPage()
    }
    

    private func openMicrophoneTestPage() {
        let testURL = URL(string: "https://mictests.com/")!
        let request = URLRequest(url: testURL)
        webView.load(request)
    }
    
    // WKScriptMessageHandler method
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if message.name == "logHandler" {
            if let messageBody = message.body as? String {
                print("JavaScript log: \(messageBody)")
            }
        }
    }
}

WebViewControllerWrapper.swift
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct WebViewControllerWrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> WebViewController {
        return WebViewController()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: WebViewController, context: Context) {
        // No update logic needed
    }
}

MicrophoneApp.swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MicrophoneApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            WebViewControllerWrapper()
        }
    }
}


I sure wouldn't recommend testing this in the Simulator. Getting microphone input to pass thru the simulator is really tricky. What if you run it on a device?

I have an iPhone X running iOS 16.7.10. To get it to work on that, I have to add @available(iOS 14.0, *) to MicrophoneApp.swift. When I run the app, the web page tells me that my browser does not support features for accessing media devices.
I tried another website in the simulator so I could get a better idea of what was being recorded and it's definitely a test pattern of notes.
This is the other site I used: https://online-voice-recorder.com/
Is there any way to get the simulator to take input from my microphone instead of using this test pattern?

Maybe with some set-ups, but I've sure never gotten it to work. There are a lot of hoops to jump thru; you have to configure I/O > Audio Input in the Simulator app, you have to give your app microphone user permission, etc. etc. It is simpler to test with a device. — But if you are thinking of submitting an app to the App Store that you have not tested on a device, that's a very bad idea in any case. If you don't have a device that runs a sufficiently recent version of iOS, you need to obtain a newer device in any case, just to be a developer (i.e. without regard to this question).
